# Get width of element after parent gets scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, width

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/j9SkE/)**

So, I've been trying to get a good jQuery way to find a client's scrollbar width. I thought I had it figured out in my fiddle, but apparently the addition of a scrollbar does not change anything of the child's width. EVEN THOUGH in dev tools (chrome, FF) the width has decreased.

```
function scrollbarWidth() {
    var div = $('<div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div>');
    $('body').append(div);

    var w1 = $(".inner").width();
    $(".test-text span:first").text(w1);
    console.log(w1);

    $(".test-div").css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
    var w2 = $(".inner").width();
    $(".test-text span:last").text(w2);

    console.log(w2);
}

scrollbarWidth();​
```

Using `innerWidth` doesn't make a difference.

How is this possible and what is a solution?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/j9SkE/2/)

Comment: Yes, but only with jQuery and not with pure JS.

Comment: Why on earth would you prefer jQuery over plain JS ?

Comment: 1. Because it's fun 2. because I want to be able to keep using the vars that I use in the rest of my jQuery document (JS).

Comment: Your variables are scoped locally in that function? Anyway, you can't use width(), you'll have to use offsetWidth and clientWidth, and because jQuery is just a handy library for people who don't want to write everything in plain JS and don't mind the loss of speed, it does'nt support those methods, so you'll have to do that with plain JS elements anyway. Something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/j9SkE/3/)

Comment: No, because I would use other variables in there as well. What I posted was just a stripped down test case. And hey, that's nice. Can you post it as an answer and explain the 'get' function? Becuase I tried to use the native JS functions, but they didn't seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: lol, have'nt been on in quite a few days, had a bad cold. Anyway, answer posted, and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function to get the width of the scrollbar :

```
function getScrollBarWidth() {
    var inner = $('<p />', {style:'width:100%;height:200px;'}),
        outer = $('<div />', {style:'position:absolute;top:0;left:0;visibility:hidden;width:200px;height:150px;overflow:hidden;'});

    outer.append(inner).appendTo($('body'));

    var w1 = inner.get(0).offsetWidth;
    outer.css('overflow', 'scroll');
    var w2 = inner.get(0).offsetWidth;
    if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.get(0).clientWidth;

    outer.remove();
    return (w1 - w2);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j9SkE/8/)

The **[get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)** function gets the native javascript DOM element, which is needed as `offsetWidth` is a native javascript method, and does not work on a jQuery "element". It could also have been written :

```
var w1 = inner[0].offsetWidth;
```

Comment: Thanks again, and hope you get well soon! Cheers. Oh, and you might want to add your Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/j9SkE/3/) to this answer, as an ecample! :)